# How to use Sauce Labs TeamCity plugin with a Visual Studio project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maven, selenium, teamcity, saucelabs

We use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) as our continuous integration server.

Now we want to **extend TeamCity to run Selenium UI tests** through the [Sauce Labs plugin](https://docs.saucelabs.com/ci-integrations/teamcity/) that allows Selenium tests to be run with different OS/browser combinations.

I've been following the [instructions supplied](https://docs.saucelabs.com/ci-integrations/teamcity/) at the Sauce Labs website, however they're based on how to use a pre-existing Java project.

I have a **ASP.NET MVC solution** and I'm unsure how to get the **plugin to run the Selenium tests** in my solution.

Comment: Mostly the same configurations for apply for all the language. Just choose the build and VCS of your choice and proceed. The driver factory and other capability settings are most obvious. Do let us know if you have a specific issue.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  Seems like the SauceLabs docs are older and no not reflect a recent TC version